# Set my own fixed X-axis value in a grid chart? Including symbols like "<" and ">" (QlikView)

Tags: datagrid, fixed, qlikview

So Im creating this grid-chart and I really want to have the following values in my X-Axis:

- "<10"
- "<20"
- ">20"

I want my graph to look something like the following graph, in the link below:

[Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aor6v.jpg)

The nodes X values does not have the lesser than (<) or bigger than(>) symbols, they are just numbers spanning from 1-30 with no extra characters. Chosing only that field as the x-axis doesnt do it, ofc. I only want those three specified values, containing the symbols (< and >), in the X-axis.

I feel like this should be a simple thing to solve, but I've tried for a while now without any succes...

Sorry about the poor example, hopefully you understand what i'm saying

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Class function](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/class.htm).

The class function assigns the first parameter to a class interval. The result is a dual value with a<=x

You could create a `grid chart` and use PplWatched and Rating as dimensions with expression count(id) using the following testdata:

```
Data:
load
    id, class(PplWatched, 10) as PplWatched, Rating
;
load * inline [
id, PplWatched, Rating
1, 14, 4
2, 2, 2
3, 19, 5
4, 30, 4
5, 9, 1
6, 45, 5
];
```

Comment: Hmm, so how should this be implemented? I've tried adding a calculated dimension: =Class(PeopleWatched, 10). But what if there movies that have a value above 20, let's say 50. Then i want them to be on the right side of the ">20" value in the x axis. Having specified 10 as the second parameter in the class function will just make more "buckets"

Comment: @Quarry123 Updated my answer.

Comment: I dont quiet understand how this could help me, but it's probably my inexperience talking :). Can I with the help of the Class method achieve the graph in the link  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aor6v.jpg ? With the exact same labels on the x axis? I just dont see it. For what i understand, Class method gives ranges of numbers, but I want the last "range" to be infinite, all plots over 20 "pplWatched" should be at the right side of "20>". It also seems that the plots are stacking, maybe I should use a scatterplot instead. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question btw :)